# MySQL not executing (Java)

Tags: java, mysql

For some reason I'm not able to update my database using this code. Can someone help me out? What I've got is when a player completes a certain task it records the time it took them if and only if their time is lower than the best recorded time.

```
    public void setScores(MapleCharacter chr, int mapid, float time) {
    Connection con1 = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT time from jumpquests WHERE characterid = ? AND mapid = ?");
        ps.setInt(1, chr.getId());
        ps.setInt(2, chr.getMapId());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            if (time < rs.getFloat("time")) {
                executeScores(chr, mapid, time);
            }
        } else {
            executeScores(chr, mapid, time);
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        System.out.println("Ran into exception.");
    }
}

public void executeScores(MapleCharacter chr, int mapid, float time) {
    System.out.println("Setting scores for " + chr.getName() + " for map " + mapid + " at time " + time);
    Connection con1 = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con1.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO jumpquests (characterid, mapid, time) values (?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1, chr.getId());
        ps.setInt(2, chr.getMapId());
        ps.setFloat(3, time);
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Executing scores ran into exception.");
    }
}
```

Comment: don't output a fixed (useless) error message. if mysql throws an error, then have the `catch` spit out the actual error message from mysql.

Comment: Do you get an exception of some sort?

Comment: What exactly is not working? You have an error? You should also consider logging the messages & stacktrace from exceptions and not only your custom messages.

Comment: I know it's not going to the catch because it's never printed though.

Comment: I left out ps.executeUpdate() lol. I'll see if it's all good now.

Comment: you do nothing in executeScores method. Why? Because you only created PreparedStatement and then you didnt execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about anything related to `JAVA` but your `REPLACE INTO` SQL statement includes reserve word `time` which needs to be escaped using backtique like below. See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) for more information.

```
REPLACE INTO jumpquests (characterid, mapid, time) values (?,?,?)
                                               ^........Here
```

Should be

```
REPLACE INTO jumpquests (characterid, mapid, `time`) values (?,?,?)
```

Comment: Also, if I were to retrieve the top 10 times recorded in the table, how would I do that and then convert it into a 10 line string that can be printed?

Comment: That's not part of this question. Consider posting a separate question for the same. If you just need the top 10 records then use a order by with limit clause like `order by comscolumn limit 10`